# SQL Turn 1 field, multiple records into 1 record multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, self-join

If I were more experienced, I'd be able to use similar "merge rows" questions to figure this out, but I can't get them to work. I've got about 2000 "garages" in an accdb with certain categories (actually clinics with patient data, but simplified here). Below is an example of how the data exists for one garage:

```
Garage ID   Car_Color        Sub_Type?   Color_Count
    42       Blue            Striped        5
    42       Blue                           10
    42       Red                            23
    42       Yellow                         2
```

I need to make each garage into a single record with each color as a separate field with the counts, desired output shown here:

```
Garage ID   Blue Cars (total)  Blue Cars (striped)   Red Cars  Yellow Cars   Orange Cars
    42         15                    5                  23          2             0
```

There is one category with a sub-type, shown here as "Blue Cars" and "Blue Cars (striped)". For those, I would need to sum the "Blue" count without a sub-type with the other "Blue" count to get the total "Blue" count. I would then list the Blue sub-type as a separate field. Most garages don't have orange cars listed, so I would need to have the record show a 0 for that field when there is no record of orange cars, but reflect the count if there is a record for it.

This seems so similar to other self-joins, but I can't get the count aspect to work or the '0' for no record.

Comment: Look into Crosstab queries.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an aggregate function with the [`IIF()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) expression:

```
select [Garage ID],
  sum(IIF(Car_color='Blue', Color_Count, 0)) as BlueCarsTotal,
  sum(IIF(Car_color='Blue' AND [Sub_Type?]='Striped', Color_Count, 0)) as BlueCarsStripedTotal,
  sum(IIF(Car_color='Red', Color_Count, 0)) as RedCarsTotal,
  sum(IIF(Car_color='Yellow', Color_Count, 0)) as YellowCarsTotal,
  sum(IIF(Car_color='Orange', Color_Count, 0)) as OrangeCarsTotal
from yourtable
group by [Garage ID]
```

If you were doing this in another database that allows `CASE` expressions the query would be:

```
select [Garage ID],
  sum(case 
       when Car_color='Blue' 
       then Color_Count else 0 end) as BlueCarsTotal
  sum(case 
       when Car_color='Blue' AND [Sub_Type?]='Striped' 
       then Color_Count else 0 end) as BlueCarsStripedTotal,
  sum(case 
       when Car_color='Red' 
       then Color_Count else 0 end) as RedCarsTotal,
  sum(case 
       when Car_color='Yellow' 
       then Color_Count else 0 end) as YellowCarsTotal,
  sum(case 
       when Car_color='Orange' 
       then Color_Count else 0 end) as OrangeCarsTotal
from yourtable
group by [Garage ID]
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew that function. That opens up a whole new world for me. I've seen some of your other answers, bluefeet, and I feel privileged to have you answer my question. It works perfectly for what I needed. Thank you very much.  Your SQL kung fu is immensely strong.

Answer (score 3):

A crosstab may suit:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Garages.Color_Count) AS SumOfColor_Count
SELECT Garages.GarageID
FROM Garages
GROUP BY Garages.GarageID
PIVOT [Car_Color] & " " & [sub_type?];
```

Comment: Thank you, Remou. This works well and is an elegant solution. Bluefeet's solution gave me a little more versatility, and having the zeroes printed helps this be more usable for me in some data-submission code I put it into. Your response is educational to me, though, and I appreciate it for the future use I'll certainly get from it.